# Length of a curve under a non-Euclidean norm in the integral form.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, curves

Let $V$ be a normed space. Let $\gamma\colon [a,b] \rightarrow V$ be continuous. Then $\gamma$ is a curve.

Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$, then $$\Lambda(\gamma, P) := \sum_{i=1}^n \| \gamma(x_i) - \gamma(x_{i-1})\|$$
We usually define the length of that curve as 
$$\Lambda(\gamma) := \sup_P \Lambda(\gamma, P)$$

A classical theorem of analysis is if $\|\cdot\|$ is an Euclidean norm and $\gamma \in C^1$, then:
$$\Lambda(\gamma) = \int_a^b \| \gamma'(t)\| dt$$

Is the theorem true if $\|\cdot\|$ is not an Euclidean norm? The proof in Rudin's Principles of the Mathematical Analysis uses this at the start.

Comment: You want $\gamma$ to be _absolutely continuous_ here, even for the Euclidean case. And yes, it's still true for general norms, and the same proof should work.

Comment: In Rudin, p.137, there's no word about absolute continuity. And the proof depends on theorem 6.25: $$\left\| \int_a^b f \right\| \le \int_a^b \| f \|$$, where the first statement uses the definition of Euclidean norm.

Comment: @sandwich but the wiki article says that the absolute continuity is strongly connected with the integrability of the derivative. And we obviously say implicitly, that what we wrote makes sense, that the function $\gamma'$ is Riemann-integrable

Comment: Rudin assumes that $\gamma'$ is continuous; this is an assumption you omitted from the question. It is far stronger than absolute continuity of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

In Rudin's PMA (Theorem 6.27) $\gamma$ is assumed continuously differentiable. The proof given there works for general normed spaces with no changes: see below.   However, it invokes the integral triangle inequality 
$$
\left\|\int_a^b \mathbf f(t)\,dt \right\| \le \int_a^b \left\|\mathbf f(t)\right\|\,dt 
\tag{1}$$
with $\mathbf f = \gamma'$. Since the proof of (1), Theorem 6.25, explicitly involves the Euclidean norm, a more general proof should be supplied. Here it is.

Let $I = \int_a^b \mathbf f(t)\,dt$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem there exists a unit-norm functional $\varphi\in V^*$ such that $\varphi(I)=\|I\|$. The function $\varphi\circ \mathbf f$ is continuous, as a composition of continuous functions. Also, $\varphi\circ \mathbf f \le \|\mathbf f\|$ because $\varphi$ has unit norm. Therefore, 
$$
\|I\| = \varphi (I) = \int_a^b \varphi(\mathbf f(t))\,dt \le   
\int_a^b \|\mathbf f(t)\|\,dt $$
as claimed.

---

For completeness, I sketch the  proof of Theorem 6.27. The integral triangle inequality gives one half of it:

$$
\Lambda(\gamma, P)
= \sum_i \left\|\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \gamma'(t)\,dt \right\| 
\le \sum_i \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \left\|\gamma'(t)\right\| \,dt   
=  \int_{a}^{b} \left\|\gamma'(t)\right\| \,dt 
$$

The converse: by the mean value theorem, each difference $\|\gamma(x_i)-\gamma(x_{i-1})\|$ is equal to $\|\gamma'(t_i)\|(x_i-x_{i-1})$  for some $t_i\in (x_{i-1},x_i)$. This implies $L(P, \|\gamma'\|, dt)\le \Lambda(\gamma, P)\le \Lambda(\gamma)$. Since the integral $\int_{a}^{b} \left\|\gamma'(t)\right\| \,dt$ is the supremum of $L(P, \|\gamma'\|, dt)$ over $P$, it follows that 
$$\int_{a}^{b} \left\|\gamma'(t)\right\| \,dt \le  \Lambda(\gamma)$$

Comment: Can we go without the Hahn-Banach theorem? I have absolutely no knowledge of functional analysis.